# Dropzone: support for animated GIF?

Tags: angularjs, ffmpeg, image-uploading, dropzone.js, animated-gif

I'm using http://www.dropzonejs.com/ to upload images and videos.

The upload part works well but the preview image works well for static image (png, jpeg, svg, etc.) but not for animated image like GIF.
My idea was also to use ffmpeg to extract a GIF from a video (in order to show it to the user).

So my question is : 
Do you know if Dropzone can support it ?
If not do you have a better alternative ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Dropzone does support animated gifs.

However, it does not seem to support resizing of animated gifs. If you have configured Dropzone to accept 'image/gif' and also have a resizeWith or resizeHeight options configured then the animated gif will not work.

You can override transformFile like so as to ignore resizing of gifs.

```
const zone = new Dropzone(this.dropzone, {
  url: this.dropzoneFileApiUrl,
  resizeWidth: this.resize ? 1920 : null,
  acceptedFiles: 'image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif',
  // Override transform file to ignore gifs
  transformFile: function(file, done) {
    if ((this.options.resizeWidth || this.options.resizeHeight) && file.type.match(/image.*/) && file.type !== 'image/gif') {
      return this.resizeImage(file, this.options.resizeWidth, this.options.resizeHeight, this.options.resizeMethod, done);
    } else {
      return done(file);
    }
  }
});
```